# If a well-formed formula is equal to another well-formed formula, does that mean their variables are equal too?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

For example, if I set $\to p_{1}q_{1} = \to p_{2}q_{2}$, does that mean $p_{1}=p_{2}$ and $q_{1}=q_{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equal formulas have equal "operator" and equal "operands"